# Is there a universal symbol for transformation or operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

If I'm talking about a bunch of transformations (translation, rotation, scale, skew, etc) and I want to state $A$ [some transformation] $= B$, what would be the symbol for [some transformation] or correct way to express it?

Like
$3 +x =5$, where I look at $+x$ as translation by $x$ amount
or

$3 × x =5$, where I look at $× x$ as scaling by $x$ amount

Could I have something in there instead of $× x$ or  $+x$ that would be more generalized with compacting transformation and value?

I ask this because then it would be easier to talk about a generalization of an inverse operation, so that I could find A by $A = 5. (3.A)^{-1}$, or something like that, I don't know.

Sorry if this comes out as all nonsense.

Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for a generic name for a transformation, $T$ is popular, as is $f$.

Comment: You could write $T \in \mathrm{Fun}(X, Y)$ to denote that $T$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: It is easier if you look at $3+x$ as translation by 3, not by $x$. Then you can interpret the equation $3+x=5$ as $f(x)=5$ where the function $f$ is defined by $f(x)=3+x$ (for some suitable domain). Then solving the equation $f(x)=5$ amounts to finding the inverse image of 5; i.e., the solution set is all $x\in f^{-1}(5)$, where I'm interpreting inverse images as sets, since in general $f$ need not be injective (though it is in this example). I think this is what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what kind of transformation are you looking for? Without any specifics, transformations are functions, and there are a lot of functions and types of functions you could define from a linear operator $A$ to a linear operator $B$.

One thing to know is that the set of all $m \times n $ matrices is a vector space of dimension $m \times n $, so if $A \in M(m_1,n_1), B \in M(m_2,n_2)$, if you're looking for the set of possible linear transformations on those two spaces, it's the set of $(m_1 \times n_1) \times (m_2 \times n_2) $ matrices.

There's not really anything special to see there--it's mostly just a repitition of the same structure you'd see in your original vector space and its associated linear transformations. When you're looking at subsets of matrices, sometimes you get special matrix groups that behave nicely and we like looking at those and examining their properties, but talking in general terms? No, not that I'm aware of.